# Use two model classes using same table in entity framework - mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to use the the same table, tblLogin which has the below fields:
UserName,UserType,UserEmail,Password.

I have two types of forms. One for Login where only 2 fields are required ie. userName and Password.
Another form has all 4 fields for CRUD functionality.

I have created one model class with DataAnnotation - [Required] for 2 columns and have created another class with [Required] for all four columns as per need.

It gives me error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The entity types 'AdminUser' and 'Login' cannot share table 'tblLogin' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary
```

Code is as below for 2 model classes:

Login.cs

```
[Table("tblLogin")]
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    public int adminId { get; set; }
    public string adminName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide your Email ID",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string adminEmail { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide your password",AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string adminPassword { get; set; }
    public string adminType { get; set; }
}
```

AdminUser.cs

```
[Table("tblLogin")]
public class AdminUser
{
    [Key]
    public int adminId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string adminName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your Email ID", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string adminEmail { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string adminPassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string adminType { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to mvc4.

Comment: please clarify you text/code. It is unreadable

Comment: You need to create a base type that both classes inherit from if you want to map records from different classes to a single table.  See here for details. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: imho, you are mixing DTO/Model classes whit POCO/Entity classes. The model layer seems to be missing. Do not map `Login` and `AdminUser` to a table. Those classes are models. Use another class `DbUSer` as an entity and map `Login` and `AdminUser` to DbUser in your controllers. DO NOT MAP MODEL TO DATABASE.

Comment: On a side note, there should never ever never be a Password field in the database. It should rather be two fields named something like PasswordSalt and PasswordHash... [http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html] And if you're really hardcore the salt should also be stored somewhere else :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In exception additional info said: The entity types 'AdminUser' and 'Login' cannot share table 'tblLogin'
For each DB table you must create only one class.

Comment: I'm not mention that it is impossible. And my ansver isn't totally wrong.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood "each DB table you must create only one class".

Answer (score 0):

WE did find the answer by using just one model class that is login.cs as it was and in our controller under the insert and edit function we wrote the below code and successfully achieved server side validation.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.adminName))
                ModelState.AddModelError("adminName", "Name field is Required");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.adminType))
                ModelState.AddModelError("adminType", "Please select the type of User");
```

Thanks for your suggestions